# Sequelize 4: Use native ES6 promise instead of Bluebird promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, es6-promise, bluebird

Can one configure sequelize, so that it will use native es6 promise instead of their bluebird copy?

According to their [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html) with sequelize 4 they're using an independent copy of bluebird. But I would like to use native es6 promises.

Example code:

```
public find(selector: object): Promise<ClientEntity[]> {
  // Client is of type Model<ClientModel>; see sequelize-typescript
  return ClientModel.findAll(selector)
    .then(res => res.map(e => e.toJSON()))
    .catch(err => console.warn('PgClientModel#find', err));
}
```

Which shows the following error: `Type 'Bluebird<void | any[]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ClientEntity[]>'. Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'Bluebird<void | any[]>'`.

Options I see right now:

1. Use bluebird
2. Within the bluebird's `then` and `catch` block I could `resolve` and `reject` via a native es6 promise. But I actually don't like that idea.

I'm using the following packages

```
"sequelize": "^4.31.2",
"sequelize-typescript": "^0.6.2",
"typescript": "^2.6.2"
```

EDIT: Solved by changing the return type to `PromiseLike`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting this:

```
Sequelize.Promise = global.Promise
```

Comment: TypeScript tells me that the `Promise` property is read-only. But no problem, I've changed the return type of my `find` method to `PromiseLike`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible with the current version. It seems that the library replaces the `Promise` keyword with an instance of the Bluebird library.

// @see here
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/fa587acc050b06db6ef6b69355f7d9350d6c01da/lib/promise.js#L3